# How to use custom Playwright Test Page fixture from separate repository with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I am trying to create framework on top of playwright where custom fixtures and other methods can be there. All my tests related project can use framework repository.

With that, I maintain a repository @test/framework where I've defined custom Playwright Test fixture which is overriding existing page fixture to navigate to "https://google.com" before every test. I'm encountering a type error when I try to import and use these fixture in my test cases in a separate repository.

In @test/framework repository, within fixtures.ts, I have:

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';

export const test = base.extend({
  page: async ({ page }, use) => {
    await page.goto("https://google.com");
    await use(page);
  }
});
```

in another repository, I install my framework project with `npm install @test/framework` and using in google.spec.ts as

```
import { test } from '@test/framework';

test('Google', async ({page}) => {
  console.log(await page.title()); // Google
})
```

now, running `npx playwright test` gives error as **First argument must use the object destructuring pattern: _a**

having the same fixture in same test projects rather than separate repository is working fine.

Repository to reproduce the issue
framework repo = https://github.com/Ankit3794/playwright-test-framework
test repo = https://github.com/Ankit3794/playwright-tests

Clone test repo and run `npx playwright test`

Comment: I don't see `@test/framework` on npm. Is this a private package? What steps can I use to reproduce the problem on a bare environment?

Comment: yes it's published in private azure feed. but you can simply create one separate repo with `npm init`. then add one file as `fixture.ts` as mentioned above. `npx tsc && npm pack` for local package. install that .tar.gz in another repo with `npm install <path of tar.gz>`

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit much work for me to bother but if you [edit] it into the question someone may be able to help. My advice is to try to make it as easy as possible if you want an answer. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, I have created two repos, one for framework at https://github.com/Ankit3794/playwright-test-framework and one for tests at https://github.com/Ankit3794/playwright-tests. Issue is reproducible with that. If you clone https://github.com/Ankit3794/playwright-tests repo and run `npx playwright test`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the efforts. I'll take a look if I have time.